# Wordpress widget with ACF not displaying values

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a custom widget based on this code [here](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/09/28/creating-a-custom-widget-with-advanced-custom-fields-pro-in-wordpress/). However when I try to display the [ACF values](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-widget/) in the front-end and they aren't displaying. Am I supposed to be editing something in the 'sanitize widget' section?

```
/**
 * Adds custom widget.
 */

class Custom_Widget extends WP_Widget {

//Register widget with WordPress.
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
      'custom_widget', // Base ID
      __('Social Links', 'text_domain'), // Name
      array( 'description' => __( 'Social links for menu', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
    );
}

//Front-end display of widget.
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php the_field('twitter_link', 'widget_' . $widget_id); ?>">twitter</a></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <?php echo $args['after_widget'];
}

//Back-end widget form.
public function form( $instance ) {


}

//Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

    return $instance;
    }
}

// register Custom_Widget widget
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
    register_widget( 'Custom_Widget' );
});
```

In the front-end this prints out:

```
<section id="custom_widget-2" class="widget widget_custom_widget">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">twitter</a></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I'm adding my values using ACF, which you can see here:
[image]

Here is my widget with the data saved:
[image]

Comment: do you need that  <?php  inside widget ? just checking

Comment: @zod Yes that `<?php` is needed, its starting the next block of php code...

Comment: you mean the <?php thats here: <?php echo $args['after_widget'];

Comment: Where are you setting the value for `twitter_link`? You have removed the contents of the form() function, which is where the value would normally be added. My guess is that there is no value to show, because I can't see how it's getting a value anywhere

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've updated my question so you can see how ACF works

Comment: If you `echo` the contents of `$instance` in `widget()`, do you see anything at all related to your ACF fields? What happens if you set a default value for `twitter_link` in your ACF Field Group? Just trying to figure out if the issue is that the widget isn't saving the values, or the widget code isn't picking up the ACF group at all.

Comment: If I use <?php echo $instance;?> I just get Array back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152455/discussion-between-fluffykitten-and-probablybest).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following, it looks as if the widget ID is not being returned properly:

```
//Front-end display of widget.
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_field('twitter_link', 'widget_' . $args['widget_id']); ?>">twitter</a></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <?php echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```